# Geeting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz' in composer DAG run

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am doing Bigquery operation in composer DAG and getting the following error :

```
Event with job id 36cc0fe962103bf2bb7a9c Failed
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,807] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,806] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'    from google.cloud.bigquery.routine import RoutineReference\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,807] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,807] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/routine/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,810] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,808] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'    from google.cloud.bigquery.enums import DeterminismLevel\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,810] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,808] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/enums.py", line 21, in <module>\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,811] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,808] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'    from google.cloud.bigquery.query import ScalarQueryParameterType\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,812] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,809] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/query.py", line 23, in <module>\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,812] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,809] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'    from google.cloud.bigquery.table import _parse_schema_resource\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,812] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,809] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 23, in <module>\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,813] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,809] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b'    import pytz\n'
[2021-08-19 15:13:07,813] {base_task_runner.py:113} INFO - Job 263145: Subtask sample [2021-08-19 15:13:07,809] {pod_launcher.py:125} INFO - b"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'\n"
```

I didn't use pytz in my airflow or BQ method . I have tried to add pytz in my composer environment but it didn't work.Please suggest.

Comment: Seems like that's one of the dependencies from the package you're using, not that you're using that specifically. How did you install `google-cloud-bigquery`? Try reinstalling that.

Comment: Yes , the answer worked for me. thanks

Comment: @PrithwirajSamanta please close this question by accepting the answer by clicking the check mark on the left side of Ricco's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the breakage https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/885 and a fix for this is released on [Bigquery version 2.24.1](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/pull/879).

You can update your bigquery dependency using the command `gcloud composer environments update`. See [Installing a Python dependency from PyPI](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package) for more details.

For testing purposes, environment has **Composer Version=1.16.14** and **Airflow Version=1.10.15**. Using the pre installed packages listed in [Cloud Composer pre installed packages](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions), I only copied the Google dependencies and updated the packages below. This is because they are dependencies of Bigquery as per [Bigquery constraints](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/master/testing/constraints-3.6.txt).

- google-cloud-bigquery==2.24.1
- google-api-core==1.29.0
- grpcio==1.38.1

**Full requirements.txt:**

```
google-ads==4.0.0
google-api-core==1.29.0
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-apitools==0.5.31
google-auth==1.28.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3
google-cloud-automl==2.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.24.1
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.1.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.1.0
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.0
google-cloud-build==2.0.0
google-cloud-container==1.0.1
google-cloud-core==1.6.0
google-cloud-datacatalog==3.1.0
google-cloud-dataproc==2.3.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.3
google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
google-cloud-kms==2.2.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==2.2.0
google-cloud-memcache==0.3.0
google-cloud-monitoring==2.0.0
google-cloud-os-login==2.1.0
google-cloud-pubsub==2.3.0
google-cloud-pubsublite==0.3.0
google-cloud-redis==2.1.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.36.2
google-cloud-tasks==2.2.0
google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1
google-cloud-translate==1.7.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.1
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-cloud-workflows==0.2.0
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.38.1
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
```

**Command:**

```
gcloud composer environments update your-composer-environment-name --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt --location your-composer-location
```